# How to Record silence without MIC

Tags: c#, audio-recording, naudio

I have a desktop application in C# that records audio from MIC using NAudio library. The application starts recording from default input device if MIC is connected to the system. The output wave file is saved.
I want to record silent to the output file if MIC is not connected, How can I feed a dummy MIC or virtual MIC to starts recording from if real mic is not connected.

Thanks
Here's the Code:

```
class AudioRecorder
    {
        private WaveIn waveIn = null;
        private WaveFileWriter waveWriter = null;
        public AudioRecorder()
        {
            if (WaveIn.DeviceCount > 0) //Means there is a mic
            {
                waveIn = new WaveIn();
                waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0; //default device
                waveIn.DataAvailable += WaveIn_DataAvailable;
            }
            else
            {
                //I want to add the virtual mic that will send only silent signal
            }
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            waveIn.StartRecording();
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            waveIn.StopRecording();
        }
        private void WaveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveWriter == null)
                waveWriter = new WaveFileWriter("output.wav", new WaveFormat(44100, 2));
            waveWriter.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: Can your code detect if the MIC is connected or not?

Comment: Yes I check from WaveIn.DeviceCount > 0
It means there is an input device

Comment: Just write zeroes to the waveWriter?

Comment: You would write bytes of 0 (actually, it's probably 16bit words, depends on the wav format), at 44.1kps.  The header is the important bit, as long as that describes the audio format that follows.

Comment: @Neil I understand your point but the issue is I have bind some input device with WaveIn which I can't if there is no MIC
if (WaveIn.DeviceCount > 0) //Means there is a mic
            {
                waveIn = new WaveIn();
                waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0; //default device
                waveIn.DataAvailable += WaveIn_DataAvailable;
            }
            else
            {
                //I want to add the virtual mic that will send only silent signal
            }

Comment: In Constructor, what would I provide for DeviceNumber because it will fire WaveIn_DataAvailable if the DeviceNumber is not provided

Comment: If there is no mic, then you are going to have to do things for yourself.  Callbacks from the audio device will not work, so you will either have to mock out something that calls `WaveIn_DataAvailable` yourself, or create some other way.  You want to record silence when there is no microphone - welcome to the world of edge cases !